# Sencha Touch access method in parent view

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to access a function from a component initialize. New to Sencha Touch/Ext.js, so not sure how scope works. I have 'spin' listeners in the 'control' which seem to work well, when incremented.

Simplified Code:

```
Ext.define('App.view.CreateChallenge', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    fullscreen: true,
    xtype: 'CreateChallenge',
    config:{ 
        items[
            xtype: 'spinnerfield',
            itemId: 'mySpin',
            initialize:function(){
                App.view.Challenge.doThis();
            }
        ],
    control:{
        '#mySpin' : {
            spin: 'doThis'

        }
    }
    },
    doThis:function(){
       console.log('dooing this');
    }
});
```

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not override `initialize` method in the config block, the proper place for that is in `Ext.define`.

Then, in `initialize`, you can call `App.view.CreateChallenge.doThis()`. But it just an ordinary function, its scope is the global `window` object, so you don't have access to the object of `App.view.CreateChallenge`.

To find a container reference from its children, you can use `Ext.Component.up()`. In your case, it will look like:

```
initialize: function() {
    …
    this.up('CreateChallenge').doThis(); // find container by xtype then call its method
}
```

We are not there yet! If you try, you are going to get an `undefined` from `this.up(…)`. This is because the container isn't finished constructing while its children are initializing. So, if you need a reference of the container in the `initialize` method, you need to wait until the container is ready, such as the `painted` event.

Then, you will end up something looks like:

```
initialize: function() {
    …
    this.on('painted', function () {
        this.up('CreateChallenge').doThis(); // find container by xtype then call its method
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ye Liu. Thanks for the tip regarding rewriting the initialize. I've been trying to comprehend delegates, controllers, refs and been getting dizzy trying to process it all. The on painted really helps since I was getting dom not found errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use

```
VIEW/This .getParent()
```

Comment: Thanks @Fawar. I'm starting to realize that there are two types of traversals with ext/sencha: dom and component.

Comment: No problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, you were trying to achieve the DOM element Parent and not the component Parent is that it?

Comment: Component parent... but now I know both.

Comment: Just so you know, .getParent() will give you the Component's Parent and not the DOM one.